# Limit of integrals around the origin

Tags: real-analysis

Let $1<Y<2$. Why is the following true?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{\delta}^1x^{-Y}e^{-x/\delta}dx=0
\end{align*}

Comment: i feel it's obvious (for me ) :-) .

Comment: Do you know under what conditions you are able to interchange the limit with integral?

Comment: According to Mathematica, when $Y = 3/2$ your integral is equal to $$-2e^{-1/\delta}+\frac{\frac{2}{e}+2\sqrt{\pi } \operatorname{erf}(1)-2\sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\delta}}\right)}{\sqrt{\delta}}$$ which tends to $+\infty$ as $\delta \to 0^+$, not zero.  Here $\operatorname{erf}$ is the error function.  Maybe there is an error in the question?

Comment: @what'sup, perhaps you should take a second look.

Comment: Should the lower limit of integration perhaps be $\delta^{-1}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume $\delta > 0$.  Making the change of variables $x=\delta t$ yields

$$
\int_{\delta}^1 x^{-Y}e^{-x/\delta}\,dx = \delta^{1-Y} \int_1^{1/\delta} t^{-Y} e^{-t}\,dt.
$$

The new integral converges as $\delta \to 0$, so we conclude that

$$
\int_{\delta}^1 x^{-Y}e^{-x/\delta}\,dx \sim \delta^{1-Y} \int_1^\infty t^{-Y} e^{-t}\,dt
$$

as $\delta \to 0$.  In particular, if $Y>1$ then

$$
\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \int_{\delta}^1 x^{-Y}e^{-x/\delta}\,dx = +\infty.
$$

Comment: This looks good to me. I had numerically evaluated the integral using Matlab and thought it converged, must have done something wrong.